# setInterval inside a for causing function to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, setinterval

I have two functions

```
 function getImgStr(imgName){
        thisStr = '<img src="/_shared/img/discovery/200x100/'+imgName+'.jpg">';
        return thisStr;
    }
    function buildIt(imgSrc){
        console.log(imgSrc);
        $('#content').append('<div></div>');
        $('#content div:last').hide()
            .addClass('imgBox')
            .attr('id',imgSrc)
            .html(getImgStr(imgSrc))
            .slideDown(2000);
    }
```

I have an array that I am looping

```
$(function(){
        for(i=0;i<=imgList.length-1;i++){
                buildIt(imgList[i]);
        }
    });
```

works fine, no probelms.

But when I try to wrap this is a setInterval is barfs

```
$(function(){
        for(i=0;i<=imgList.length-1;i++){
            var loadIt = setInterval(function(){
                buildIt(imgList[i]);
            },1000);
        }
    });
```

the console.log in buildIt is undefined when the setInterval is there so I am assuming that the interval somehow affects the loop but I do not understand what I am doing wrong.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try writing another function with the contents of the loop and pass any variables (including the index `i`) into it.

Comment: Also you may not want to set the setInterval to a variable if you dont need to. I know clearInterval is what ends a interval timer, but overwriting that variable in the loop may affect it as well (have not tested this).

Comment: Your for loop is finished before your setInterval even runs sp it's most likely passing imgList[4] to your function.

Comment: `setInterval` acts as a loop itself. You should decide whether you want to execute your code multiple times with intervals (use `setInterval`), or right away (use an ordinary loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your clarification: If you want to load images one after the other every second, you can do something like this. You don't need a loop at all.

```
var i = 0;
var id = setInterval(function() {
    if(i === imgList.length) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        buildIt(imgList[i++]);
    }
}, 1000)
```

What this does is initialize the value of `i` to 0. `i` functions exactly like `i` in your for loop. It's essentially an index. Then, you store the value of the interval inside the variable `id`. This way you maintain a reference to the interval so that you can clear it when you are done loading the images.

Finally, inside the interval function you check to see if `i` is equal to the length of the number of images in your image list. If it is, we know that we're done loading all of them so we clear the interval. Otherwise we call the `buildIt` function for the image that corresponds to the current value of `i` and the increment the value of `i`.

Comment: Maybe I am using the setInterval wrong.  I have six images in the imgList Array and I want them to load one at a time with a second in between.

Comment: -1 Vivin, I hate to break it to you, but your solution won't work either -- see `wrong3` in my example below, which is your solution simplified for example's sake.

Comment: @EthanBrown I'm well aware of the caveats; there's nothing you have to "break" to me. OP hasn't explained what he wants to do. I went off what he described in his initial post. He never explained that he wanted to load the images one after the other, which is why I asked him for clarification. Did you not see the last line in my answer?

Comment: +1 You got to the point of what @Lance was trying to do before I did.  Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED** with [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EQMDz/)

```
   this.buildIt= function(imgSrc){
    console.log("test"+imgSrc)
    console.log(imgSrc.length)
        };

$(function(){ 
      var imgList=[
"test1","test2","test3","test4"
]
        for(i=0;i<=imgList.length;i++){

            var loadIt = setInterval(function(){
                this.buildIt(imgList);
            },1000,imgList);
        }
    });​
```

Comment: This (http://jsfiddle.net/EQMDz/1/) is probably the closest I've gotten to what I was looking for. it is a combo of the advice from everyone.  Now if I can just figure out how to clearInterval() when index == imgList.length I will be in good shape.

Comment: @Lance That's exactly what I've done in my solution (clearing the interval when `index === imgList.length`. Have you looked at it?

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATE*: I'm still not entirely clear what the OP is trying to do, but I'm going to through another solution on the heap based on my understanding.  You have N images, and you want to update those images in sequence every second.  To do that, you're going to have to combine a `setTimeout` with a `setInterval`.  The `setTimeout` will stagger the updating of the images, and the `setInterval` will cause each image to be updated in turn.  Here's how it would look:

```
function start() {
    var nImages = 5;
    for( i=0; i<nImages; i++ ) {
        (function(j){
            setTimeout( function() {
                buildIt(j);
                intervals.push(
                    setInterval( function() {
                        buildIt(j);
                    }, 1000*nImages )
                );
            }, j*1000 );
        })(i);
    }
}

function stop() {
    for( i in intervals ) {
        clearInterval( intervals[i] );
    }
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/FtCCs/

And here's my previous answer:
​
Vivin is on the right track, but his solution won't work either, as it's just pushing the closure problem further down the stack.  However, he's correct in one regard: your `buildIt` function calls are not getting the indexes you expect, but all the same index.  What you need to do is this:

```
$(function(){
    for(i=0;i<=imgList.length-1;i++){
        (function(j){
            var loadIt = setInterval(function(){
                buildIt(imgList[j]);
            },1000);
        })(i);
    }
});
```

To make perfectly clear what's going on, consider the following example:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrong1">Wrong:<br /></div>
<div id="wrong2">Wrong:<br /></div>
<div id="wrong3">Wrong:<br /></div>
<div id="right">Right:<br /></div>
```

jQuery:

```
// won't work:
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    setTimeout( function() { $('#wrong1').append(i+'<br />'); }, 500 );
}

// won't work:
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    var j = i;
    setTimeout( function() { $('#wrong2').append(j+'<br />'); }, 500 );
}

// won't work:
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    setTimeout( function() { (function(j){ $('#wrong3').append(j+'<br />'); })(i) }, 500 );
}

// works!
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    (function(j){
        setTimeout( function() { $('#right').append(j+'<br />'); }, 500 );
    })(i);
}
```

I set up a JsFiddle here to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/k3RJL/1/

In all of the "wrong" examples, the variable `i` or `j` is a closure, but by the time the function in the `setTimeout` executes, the value has changed to its final value within that closure, so they all come out the same.  Note the difference in `wrong2`: its looking at the variable `j` which is defined inside the `for` loop, so it never receives the final value of `i`, which is why it stops at 4.

​

Comment: Thanks Ethan, it seems like I am almost there and your example and explains really cleared up how to pass in info to the setTimeout. But I am still confused.  The final one that is makes as Works! is the same result as if I had 'for(i=0;i<=imgList.length-1;i++){
                buildIt(imgList[i]);
        }'  there is no delay between the loads they all load at the same time.

Comment: @Ethan, you don't even need a loop for this. You can enclose the bounds check inside the the closure.

Comment: That's because the loop sets them all to start at the same time, practically.  If you want them staggered, you'll have to be a little more clever.

Comment: -1 @EthanBrown OP wants to load the image one at a time. See my edit. I don't really understand the point of your solution or how it addresses the OP's question. You're simply setting it so that the images are loaded together after an interval. How is that any different from loading them all at the same time *without* waiting?

Comment: I see that now, Vivin.  That wasn't clear at first.  I was more concerned about the incorrect use of closures, but I'll address his other issue, too.

Comment: @EthanBrown No worries. I made the same mistake. OP wasn't very clear as to what he wanted which is why I wrote the solution the way I did. I didn't know that he wanted to load them one at a time. The problem though is that `setInterval` will keep running until it's cleared. You can check out my updated solution where I don't use a loop and I simply perform the bounds check within the closure and then clear the interval when I am done.